# how to select from array data in a select

Tags: php, arrays, select

hi i need to take from an array with data and then take data from another array with select

example this is my select:

```
<select class="cuenta-save-1" name="pais" id="pais">
                <option value="">Pa&iacute;s</option>
                {foreach from=$tsPaises key=code item=pais}
                    <option value="{$code}" {$pais}</option>
                {/foreach}
            </select>
```

fom this i want to select another datta:

```
<select name="estado" id="estado" class="cuenta-save-1">
                {foreach from=$tsEstados key=code item=estado}
                    <option value="{$code+1}" {$estado}</option>
                {/foreach}
            </select>
```

the first select have an array like this:

```
$tsPaises = array(
'AF' => 'Afganist&aacute;n',
'AL' => 'Albania',
'DE' => 'Alemania',
'DZ' => 'Argelia',
'AD' => 'Andorra',
'AO' => 'Angola',
'AI' => 'Anguila',
'AG' => 'Antigua y Barbuda',
'AQ' => 'Ant&aacute;rtida',
'SA' => 'Arabia Saudita',
'AR' => 'Argentina',
'AM' => 'Armenia',
'AW' => 'Aruba',
'AU' => 'Australia',
'AT' => 'Austria',
'AZ' => 'Azerbaiy&aacute;n');
```

and he second one the region:

```
     $estados['AD'] = array(7 => 'Andorra la Vella',2 => 'Canillo',3 => 'Encamp',8 => 'Escaldes-Engordany',4 => 'Massana',5 => 'Ordino',6 => 'Sant Juli&agrave; de L&ograve;ria');
     $estados['AO'] = array(19 => 'Bengo',1 => 'Benguela',2 => 'Bi&eacute;',3 => 'Cabinda',4 => 'Cuando Cubango',5 => 'Cuanza Norte',6 => 'Cuanza Sul',7 => 'Cunene',8 => 'Huambo',9 => 'Hu&iacute;la',10 => 'Luanda',17 => 'Lunda Norte',18 => 'Lunda Sul',12 => 'Malanje',14 => 'Moxico',13 => 'Namibe',15 => 'U&iacute;ge',16 => 'Zaire');    
     $estados['AG'] = array(1 => 'Barbuda',3 => 'Saint George',4 => 'Saint John',5 => 'Saint Mary',6 => 'Saint Paul',7 => 'Saint Peter',8 => 'Saint Philip');
     $estados['AQ'] = array(1 => 'Antarctica (general)');
```

if in the first select i select a country code i want the second one loads the region from the country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach like this to get the key and value:

```
<select class="cuenta-save-1" name="pais" id="pais">
    <option value="">Pa&iacute;s</option>
    <?php
    foreach($tsPaises as $code => $pais) {
        echo '<option value="' . $code . '">' . $pais . '</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```